# The modifying in nested array

Tags: javascript

I created an nested array with empty array for each item. I want to input the data to each index with push method. But instead of inserting to each item the data is filled to all item. Could someone help me explain this behavior? Thanks

```js
let input = new Array(4).fill([]);
let data = [[0,1],[3,2],[2,1]];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   const key = data[i][1]
   const value = data[i][0]
   input[key].push(value)
}
console.log(input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to how Array fill behaves. When you pass an object (an empty array in this case) as the parameter, all of your elements have the same reference.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#value

Comment: Thanks that's is a great reference to understand this problem

Answer (score 1):

Array is an object.. you are filling the array with same object and pushing to same object reference

```js
let input = new Array();
let data = [[0,1],[3,2],[2,1]];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   input[key] = input[key] || [];
   const key = data[i][1]
   const value = data[i][0]
   input[key].push(value)
}
console.log(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've filled the array with ***the same*** empty array

Think of it like this

```
const a = []
const b = new Array(4).fill(a)
```

a is inserted into the array four times and any index of b is a reference to a.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays that was filled inside `input` variable is the same and when you change one of this array you change all linked arrays also. You can read more about it here: https://javascript.info/object-copy

```
let input = new Array(4).fill([]);
let a = []
let b = []
let c = a

console.log(input[0] === input[1]) ---> true
console.log(a === b) ---> false
console.log(a === c) ---> true
```